# Access violation while trying to call a procedure from another Unit

Tags: delphi

I have two different units in Delphi.
The first unit has a procedure named `ApplyUpdates` and all it does is run a query.

I need to access this procedure from another unit, and when I do so I get an error message that says "Access violation"".

The procedure in the first unit is:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplyUpdates ( var AppType: string);
begin
  qryApplyUpdates.ParamByName('type').DataType := ftString;
  qryApplyUpdates.ParamByName('type').ParamType := ptInput;
  qryApplyUpdates.ParamByName('type').AsString := AppType;
  qryApplyUpdates.ExecSQL;
end;
```

From the second unit I call this procedure as:

```
var
  UserForm: TForm1;
begin
    UserForm.ApplyUpdates (AppType );
end;
```

When I debug it, it stops right at the first line of the procedure.

My question is: What am I doing wrong that I cannot access this procedure from the first unit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the form is autocreated, don't use the local variable at all:

```
// The default declared variable for an autocreated form is the classname without the prefix
Form1.ApplyUpdates(AppType);
```

If the form is not autocreated, you have to create the form before you can use it.

```
var
  UserForm: TForm1;
begin
  UserForm := TForm1.Create(nil);
  try
    UserForm.ApplyUpdates(AppType);
  finally
    UserForm.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, I will accept your answer in a few minutes